# Should Tiamat's cold breath target the ability score indicated in its save?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, dungeons-and-dragons, saving-throw, designer-reasons

The party is looking at facing Tiamat as the 20th-level epic boss fight that will end the campaign.  The evoker has only four spell slots that can directly affect her, due to her limited magic immunity, so has to choose well.

He is considering *Arcane Hand*, which when upcast has good damage output, considering her immunity to most of his damage types and her legendary saves.  However, [the *Hand*, as an object](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/134275/can-bigbys-hand-attempt-strength-and-dexterity-saving-throws), automatically fails Dex saves and so will go down pretty quickly to fire, lightning, and acid breath.  The *Hand*, as an object, is immune to poison.

I was confused about her cold breath.  [White dragon](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/16773-adult-white-dragon) cold breath is a Con save; Con is a pretty standard save against cold damage (cf. *Cone of Cold*, *Freezing Sphere*).  As an object, the *Hand* would also be immune to damage that came with a Con save.  But the statblock I have for Tiamat in Roll20 says that her white head's cold breath causes a *Dex* save.  I don't have access to the print copy of *Rise of Tiamat*.

Is the Roll20 cold breath correct, or in error?  If her printed statblock actually does call for a Dex save, is there any precedent for that - perhaps in previous editions, or any official reason why it would be different from white dragon breath?

Matswecja's [answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/206187/23547) resolved my wizard's decision by pointing out that dragon breath, including Tiamat's, as written can damage only creatures, not objects.  However, it does not explain why Tiamat's cold breath works differently from a white dragon's.  I am still seeking an explanation for this - it could be a legacy of her stats in previous editions, a deliberate change signaled somewhere, or simply an error in editing.

Comment: Just wondering(mainly because I don't have her stats): does Tiamat have a head with every kind of breath weapon?

Comment: Is this title a spoiler? Currently playing through Rise of Tiamat so maybe I should stay out of this question altogether.

Comment: @FerventHippo Yes, it contains spoilers for the end of that campaign

Comment: I can't think of a good way of de-spoilering the title without making it too vague, maybe someone with experience with the adventure can consider this.

Comment: @FerventHippo honestly, Tiamat's depicted on the cover of the book, her holy symbol includes 5 chromatic dragon heads, and I'd consider this a general knowledge, other than slight mechanical spoiler for which specific save is called for.

Comment: @FerventHippo I've edited the title to remove the specific save.  Hopefully it is not a spoiler, after 48 years and six editions of representations, that she has a cold breath.

Comment: @TieflingDragon84 Not every kind, but every kind of the chromatic dragons.

Comment: @Trish I still would like to know why the ability score save for the cold breath is Dex for Tiamat vs Con for a white dragon, and if this is a legacy of other editions, a deliberate change for 5e, or an editing mistake.  Changing the title as you did makes the question unlikely to attract the answer I am looking for.  Matszecja's answer has solved my problem of what to do in the specific adventure, but it has not answered my question.

Comment: If your question was really about the designer-reasons, then that should have been the focus. This is a good example of why one question per question is helpful.

Comment: @NautArch I thought I had one question.  I was not asking how the dragon breath affected arcane hand - I thought I understood it and was only offering it is the background reason/ justification for my question.  As it turns out, I did _not_ understand how the hand was affected by the breath, but that was my own error, not a deliberate question.

Comment: Your second to last paragraph is asking if it's correct or not. It also asks if there is lore behind the history of the breath weapon. And finally it asks if there are designer reasons for the save choice. That's three questions.

Comment: I read it as a single question that calls for an explanation/support of the answer that is likely to touch on at least one or other of the possibilities mentioned.

Comment: My intent was to ask the question about why the save was different, and offer lore and designer reasons as possible answers rather than questions in their own right.

Answer (score 22):

### Yes, the statblock for Tiamat calls for Dex save.

However, both existing statblocks of Tiamat specifically call for **creatures** to make a saving throw. This means that, as a baseline, Arcane Hand would be unaffected by any of them.

Comment: Alternatively, objects could be automatically affected by them with no save allowed.

Comment: @GreySage is there a general rule about that? Or is that a suggested house rule?

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't considered that - and it does appear consistent with dragon breath in general that it does not affect objects (which I had not noticed).  While it solves my problem, this does not fully answer my question - is there any source that explains _why_ Tiamat's white dragon breath calls for a different save than a white dragon's?  Also, when you say "both existing statblocks of Tiamat" do you mean both the print and roll20 versions of _Rise of Tiamat_?

Comment: @Kirt In Fizban's Treasury of Dragons there's a statblock for *Aspect of Tiamat*, which is a bit different from what is presented in RoT

Comment: @matszwecja I do have that, in print.  I was just attempting to understand what you meant by "both existing statblocks".  Are you saying you meant RoT and Fizzban's?

Comment: @Kirt yes, these 2 are noticeably different statblocks.

Comment: @matszwecja They are two different creatures, not two different stat blocks of the same creature. In RoT it is a Fiend, whilst in FToD it is a dragon.

Comment: One is an aspect, the other is not, but calling them 2 different creatures is way too much of a stretch, imho.

Comment: No, they are two different creatures, both for the statblock and for the description. The aspect is a sort of avatar of the fiend.

Comment: @Eddymage plus, there's other editions that have her stats.